# Generate multiple tables at once with officedown in R

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

Suppose I have a (named) list in `R`, for example the first three rows of `iris` of each `Species`:

```
library(tidyverse)
Iris <- split(iris, iris$Species) %>% map(head, n = 3)
```

Now I want to print a table in a `officedown::rdocx_document` for each element of the list including `tab.cap` and `tab.id`. I could do the following in an `R` chunk with `tab.cap = imap_chr(Iris, ~ str_c("Species ", .y, " with a maximum value Petal.Length = ", max(.x$Petal.Length))), tab.id = names(Iris)`:

```
Iris[[1]]
Iris[[2]]
Iris[[3]]
```

This works perfectly. However, of course, I don't want to call each element separately. **EDIT: NO, even that does not work, but `Iris[[1]]` (no matter which index) does. This has to be a bug?!**

I've tried `map(Iris, print)`, I've tried simply `Iris`, I've tried `for(i in 1:length(Iris)){Iris[[i]]}`,  but that does not work. Is there a way to achieve what I want? I've seen [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71928928/generate-tables-in-a-loop-with-tab-id-with-officedown-r-package) but I don't think that this is really elegant. Isn't there a way simply with vectors of `tab.cap` and `tab.id` and preferably without `flextable`?

Comment: the solution you mention is with flextable (`flextable_to_rmd()`) and is not recommended anymore: Posit now recommends using `knit_child()`, see https://ardata-fr.github.io/flextable-book/rendering.html#looping-in-r-mardown-documents and adapt the code by dropping flextables

Comment: Thank you! This is really crap, no blame (towards you). I'll try it out and then report back. Please take a look at my edit; apparently, one can exploit a bug, I don't know why it works.